# python remove line startswith MAC & TOTAL and print the first Value or index 0

Tags: python

I'm trying to filter the MAC address from a text file as it has many feilds like MAC, ADDRESS , PORT and so on.. i just tried below but it produces a LIST output
where it has blank list line and lines startswith `TOTAL` & `MAC` which i want to remove , i given it a try with my first code i have commented the line but it did not worked.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    with open('device', 'r' ) as fopen:
      readMac = fopen.read().splitlines()
      for line in readMac:
        getMAC = line.upper().split()
          #if getMAC[0] not in ('TOTAL', 'MAC'):
        print getMAC
```

> Below is the code output its producing ..

```
bash-4.1$ ./maclist2.py
['TOTAL', 'ACTIVE', 'ENTRIES', 'FROM', 'ALL', 'PORTS', '=', '312']
['MAC', 'ADDRESS', 'PORT', 'AGE', 'VLAN', 'TYPE']
[]
['0004.5G0B.54DA', '11/40', '0', '174']
['24B6.FGG8.05EC', '10/7', '0', '174']
['MAC', 'ADDRESS', 'PORT', 'AGE', 'VLAN', 'TYPE']
[]
```

> below is another code i tried  with `line.startswith` function and it
>   returns error..

```
    bash-4.1$ cat maclist.py
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    with open('device', 'r' ) as fopen:
        for line in fopen.read().splitlines():
          if not line.startswith('TOTAL', 'MAC'):
            print line.upper()

bash-4.1$ ./maclist.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./maclist.py", line 5, in <module>
    if not line.startswith('TOTAL', 'MAC'):
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Though, when i'm using only `if not line.startswith('MAC'):` then it removes the line starting with `MAC` but another line with `TOTAL` and blank line remains there.

Below is the output when i ran it with changing the code slightly `if not line.startswith('MAC'):`

```
bash-4.1$ ./maclist.py | more
TOTAL ACTIVE ENTRIES FROM ALL PORTS = 312

0004.5G0B.54DA 11/40        0       174
24B6.FGG8.05EC  10/7        0       174

45B6.FUT8.009C  10/7        0       174
```

> File sample:

```
bash-4.1$ cat device | more
Total active entries from all ports = 312
MAC Address     Port      Age      VLAN    Type

0004.5G0B.54DA 11/40        0       174
24B6.FGG8.05EC  10/7        0       174
MAC Address     Port      Age      VLAN    Type
```

45B6.FUT8.009C  10/7        0       174

Comment: Can you share a sample from the file you are trying to parse?

Comment: @Kyle .. sure i will

Comment: @Kyle .. just updated the ques with file sample

Comment: Okay gotcha.  So you basically want that first column right?

Comment: yes, that's correct .. later i want each column output to be taken separately to put them into different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the trick to get it simply with `re` and another with `s.startswith` function.. Please do let me know if it can be better further..

> 1) First code with `re` module

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import re
for line in open('device'):
  line = line.strip()
  if line != '':
    if not re.match(r'(Total|MAC)', line):
      getMac = line[:15]
      getPort = line[15:20]
      getSub = line[36:40]
      #getMAC = line[15:20]
      print(getMac.upper())
      #print(getPort.upper())
      #print(getSub.upper())
```

> 2) second code with `startswith` module

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
with open("device", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.strip()
        if data: # is not empty
          raw_data2 = data
          if not raw_data2.startswith(('Total', 'MAC')):
            getMac = raw_data2[:15]
            print(getMac.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easiest to use the re module to match the MAC addresses with a regular expression. The format is very consistent so I think might be the easiest way to parse them all out.  Below is my sample.  I am using a sample set of data from your question and put them in a file called sample_data.txt.  My solution returns **['0004.5G0B.54DA', '24B6.FGG8.05EC']**

**Note**: I am not a regular expression wizard, but this should get the job done.

```
import re


def get_data():
    pattern = re.compile(r'[a-z|A-Z|0-9]{4}\.[a-z|A-Z|0-9]{4}\.[a-z|A-Z|0-9]{4}')
    mac_addresses = None

    with open('sample_data.txt', 'r') as data_file:
        raw_data = data_file.read()
        results = pattern.findall(raw_data)
        mac_addresses = results

    return mac_addresses

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mac_addresses = get_data()
    [print(a) for a in mac_addresses]
```

Comment: when i ran it , it returns no output .

Comment: Did you save the output to the sample_data.txt file? Is there an exception or anything?  It ran find on my system.

Comment: yes, which version of python you have in, looks like something with `return` function, secondly i need this output in a plain text format meaning not in LIST , each addreess in a new line

Comment: Did you print out the result of the get_data method? My original version didn't print it to screen or anything. Updated my version above...

Comment: when i use `print` in place of `return` then it works

Comment: I updated my answer as well. Added a list comprehension to print each address on a separate line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155616/discussion-between-rockypy17-and-kyle).

Comment: Kyle , can you explain the code specially about pattern line to see how it's taking the first column so I can use it for other columns as well.